# I am not able to add google meet to a calendar event api using nodejs

Tags: google-api, google-calendar-api, google-meet

I am using google APIs to create an event and add a google meet link to that event.

Calendar event creation is working fine but I am not able to add a google meet link

```
 const response = await calendar.events.patch({
    auth: auth,
    calendarId: calendarId,
    eventId: "6df3sea0jhl6tueoos4qjr41a0",
    requestBody: {
      conferenceData: {
        createRequest: {
          requestId: "asdafas14",
        },
        conferenceSolution: {
          key: {
            type: "hangoutsMeet",
          },
        },
      },
    },
    sendNotifications: true,
    conferenceDataVersion: 1,
  });
```

With the above payload, the response is 200 but no meeting link was added

Also tried this by changing payload

```
await calendar.events.patch({
    auth: auth,
    calendarId: calendarId,
    eventId: "6df3sea0jhl6tueoos4qjr41a0",
    requestBody: {
      conferenceData: {
        createRequest: {
          requestId: "asdafas14",
          conferenceSolutionKey: {
            type: "hangoutsMeet",
          },
        },
      },
    },
    sendNotifications: true,
    conferenceDataVersion: 1,
  });
```

Response is 400 and gives the errors

```
 {
      domain: 'global',
      reason: 'invalid',
      message: 'Invalid conference type value.'
    }
```

I am using a developer service account from `https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/dashboard`

Can anyone please help me with what is wrong here? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made it work with a few changes to your code, the the following example:

```
  const response = await calendar.events.patch({
        auth: auth,
        calendarId: calendarId,
        // I replace my event ID for yours
        // so you can only copy and paste it on your code. 
        eventId: "6df3sea0jhl6tueoos4qjr41a0",
        requestBody: {
            "conferenceData": {
                "createRequest": {
                  // place "conferenceSolutionKey" inside "createRequest"
                    "conferenceSolutionKey": {
                        "type": "hangoutsMeet"
                    }, 
                    // change the request of the requestID
                    "requestId": "sample1234"
                },
            },
        },
        sendNotifications: true,
        conferenceDataVersion: 1,
    });
    console.log(response.data.hangoutLink);
```

**Reference:**

- [Events: patch](https://developers.google.com/calendar/api/v3/reference/events/patch)
- [Events Overview](https://developers.google.com/calendar/api/v3/reference/events)
- [JavaScript quickstart

](https://developers.google.com/calendar/api/quickstart/js)

---

```
const fs = require('fs').promises;
const path = require('path');
const process = require('process');
const { authenticate } = require('@google-cloud/local-auth');
const { google } = require('googleapis');

// If modifying these scopes, delete token.json.
const SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar'];
// The file token.json stores the user's access and refresh tokens, and is
// created automatically when the authorization flow completes for the first
// time.
const TOKEN_PATH = path.join(process.cwd(), 'token.json');
const CREDENTIALS_PATH = path.join(process.cwd(), 'credentials.json');

/**
 * Reads previously authorized credentials from the save file.
 *
 * @return {Promise<OAuth2Client|null>}
 */
async function loadSavedCredentialsIfExist() {
    try {
        const content = await fs.readFile(TOKEN_PATH);
        const credentials = JSON.parse(content);
        return google.auth.fromJSON(credentials);
    } catch (err) {
        return null;
    }
}

/**
 * Serializes credentials to a file compatible with GoogleAUth.fromJSON.
 *
 * @param {OAuth2Client} client
 * @return {Promise<void>}
 */
async function saveCredentials(client) {
    const content = await fs.readFile(CREDENTIALS_PATH);
    const keys = JSON.parse(content);
    const key = keys.installed || keys.web;
    const payload = JSON.stringify({
        type: 'authorized_user',
        client_id: key.client_id,
        client_secret: key.client_secret,
        refresh_token: client.credentials.refresh_token,
    });
    await fs.writeFile(TOKEN_PATH, payload);
}

/**
 * Load or request or authorization to call APIs.
 *
 */
async function authorize() {
    let client = await loadSavedCredentialsIfExist();
    if (client) {
        return client;
    }
    client = await authenticate({
        scopes: SCOPES,
        keyfilePath: CREDENTIALS_PATH,
    });
    if (client.credentials) {
        await saveCredentials(client);
    }
    return client;
}

/**
 * Makes the patch request to add the a meet link.
 *
 */
    const response = await calendar.events.patch({
        calendarId: 'primary',
        eventId: "eventId",
        requestBody: {
            "conferenceData": {
                "createRequest": {
                    "conferenceSolutionKey": {
                        "type": "hangoutsMeet"
                    }, "requestId": "sample1234"
                },
            },
        },
        sendNotifications: true,
        conferenceDataVersion: 1,
    });
    console.log(response.data.hangoutLink);
    
}

authorize().then(listEvents).catch(console.error);
```

Comment: @gisille Apologies for the delayed response. I have exactly the same thing you mentinoed. But it is not working, error is `Invalid conference type value.` Same thing is mentioned in the questions as well

Comment: Looks like this is some permission issue since the same code worked out for you.
I followed this example: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dFaV95gS_0M
Is there any wrong with creating private key like mentioned in the vidoe

Comment: Let me review for a moment, I will run some tests.

Comment: I will add the full code that I'm using as an update.

Comment: Got the issue. It is working fine with oauth2 integration but looks like there is an issue with creating credentials like mentioned in the above youtube link.

Comment: Thanks for you efforts Giselle